# one controller angularjs on multiple tempate Onsen UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Hello i am new on onsen UI, i have little question. how to put one controller angularjs on two template on ONSEN UI. for example :

1. Controler : activityController on Display Data Template
2. Controler : activityController on Form record data Template

in the that controller i have one $scope as a flag. that $scope is read by two template

instead of put activityController on body tag how to do this?